# Is there a web-based campaign creator for Vuforia?

Tags: sdk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am considering using the Vuforia SDK to create an app, but there doesn't appear to be a campaign creator similar to those of Layar (https://www.layar.com/creator/) or Metaio (http://www.metaio.com/creator/). How do you upload content and campaigns to apps using Vuforia's SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to https://developer.vuforia.com and in that on targetManager you have to upload all your content which you want to scan and their metadata.